# How do I retrieve whether a VM is off or on?

Tags: api, cloud, virtual-machine, status, vcenter

We are creating a simple panel for our users to see the status of their machines along with features like turning it off or on, we are fetching information through the vCenter API and storing the result in a MySQL database and updating it every 6 hours (Not a proper solution), now the problem in here is that when user turns off his machine through direct SSH connection or someone turns the server off manually, we miss the status and show it wrongly until the next update (every 6 hours).

My question is that how can we handle the above situation? is there any efficient way like a proper webhook or a similar way to give us the real time status of a virtual machine?

Thanks in advance, Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to monitor the vCenter events for the managed objects(VirtualMachine).

When a user turns off his machine through direct SSH connection(command: "poweroff"/"halt"..), surely VM will poweredOff in vCenter . Hence VmPoweredOffEvent will arise.

VmPoweredOffEvent - This event records when a virtual machine finished powering off.

Monitor for this event and update the status of the respective VM in DB.